# Searching most used product in sale table using structure query language

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

I am searching "Which product is the most popular one (i.e., most customers purchased it)?" I tired many sql command but i failed to search the most purchased product name  in sale table.
Description(nvarchar) and
quantity(float).

[image]

Comment: This sounds like a simple use of `count()`. What have you tried that doesn't work? And why would you have an imprecise data type of `float` for what is obviously an integer?

Answer (score 1):

this return 10 most popular item:

```
select top 10 Description , count(*) NumberOrdered
from tablename
group by Description
order by count(*) desc
```

if you want take the quantity into consideration :

```
select top 10 Description , sum(quantity) unitsold
from tablename
group by Description
order by sum(quantity) desc
```

Comment: And if i want to check before and after customer brought the most popular product? then what would b the logic.

Comment: then run this query before and after

Comment: how can i run i cannot understand

Comment: it depends , your question is so general , explain the whole scenario, maybe in a new question

Comment: What did the customers buy before and after they bought the most popular product?

Comment: in upper question we will find  most purchased product and now we want to find "what did the customers buy before and after they bought the most popular product?"